# How to use WebAPI in bash for sonarqube?

Tags: bash, rest, sonarqube

I want to write a shell script to login and get bugs for a project. I want the dashboard values like bugs, Vulnerabilities, code smells and coverage.
The url of dashboard is: http://www.example.com/dashboard?id=example_project_name.

Here is what I tried:
`curl GET -u username:password http://www.example.com/api/issues/search?project=example_project_name&types=BUG`.

So, this prints all the data. I just need the value show in the below image:

[image: Sonar project dashboard]

Basically What I want to achieve is that I’m using a Sonarqube plugin in Jenkins, so I use extended email plugin to send email for job execution and in that email I want to give details like number of bugs in the repository after the build.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after reading the documentation carefully, I got the values. Here is the script that I created.

```
#!/bin/bash
vul=$(curl -sX GET -u username:password 'http://www.example.com/api/issues/search?projectKeys=example_project_name&types=VULNERABILITY');
bug=$(curl -sX GET -u username:password 'http://www.example.com/api/issues/search?projectKeys=example_project_name&types=BUG');
no_vul=$(echo $vul | jq -r .total);
no_bug=$(echo $bug | jq -r .total);
echo "Total number of VULNERABILITIES are $no_vul"
echo "Total number of BUGS are $no_bug"
```

Here is the API [documentation URL](https://codeen-app.euclid-ec.org/sonar/web_api/api/issues).

Comment: Hi @ashutosh, documentation URL link in your post requires login...